# Mittag-Leffler function recurrence relation

Tags: calculus, special-functions, gamma-function, mittag-leffler-function

The general Mittag-Leffler function $$E_{a,b}(z)=\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^h}{\Gamma(ha+b)}$$ satifies the recurrence $$E_{a,b}(z)=zE_{a,b+a}(z)+\frac1{\Gamma(b)}.$$
I am having a hard time in proving this recurrence. Does it follow immediately from definition. I am not getting it.I think the property of Gamma function is used here. Any easy proofs? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well $\;\displaystyle zE_{a,b+a}(z)=\sum_{h=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{h+1}}{\Gamma((h+1)a+b)}$ so yes it is immediate.

For other interesting properties of the Mittag-Leffler function see this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138084/regularization-of-a-divergent-integral).

Comment: Thanks!, yes now its immediate didnt get that one though Just the work of paranthesis

Comment: Mittag-Leffler's function allows to make very nice mathematics starting with simple things like the "class 3" from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1561591/21783) to very deep mathematics. Excellent excursions!

Comment: So your answer in that thread was inspired by Mittag-Leffler function?

Comment: When I updated my answer with the "class 3" I noticed that it could be generalized to non integer values of the denominators and further linked to Mittag-Leffler (the relation between integrals and series is very interesting too).